# Question about behaviour of $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

It's possible to show that the limit of $\sin(h)/h$ as $h$ tends to $0$ is $1$, famously.

Now, someone said to me the other day, "That means that $\sin(0)/0$ is 1", and I strongly disagreed. I said to them that a limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ equals $f(a)$ only if $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ and we hadn't established that yet.

However, to establish whether $\sin(x)/x$ is continuous at $x=0$, one needs consider a sequence $f(a_0), f(a_1), f(a_2),...$, where $a_i$ is a sequence that tends to $0$, and see whether the limit of the sequence is the same as $f(0)$ - but *that's* exactly our problem! We need to know the function is continuous at $x=0$ to evaluate it there using our limit, but to know whether it is continuous at $x=0$, we need to know its evaluation there!

I apologise if my reasoning is highly fallacious, as I am only an amateur enthusiast, but what, if any, is the way out of this circular reasoning? *Is* our function continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: If $f(x)=\sin x/x$ then $f(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: So, $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$?

Comment: $f(x)$ can be extended to a continuous function $\hat{f}(x)$ where $\hat{f}(0) = 1$ and $f$ and $\hat{f}$ agree away from $0$.

Comment: Ok. Well, there we go - my initial thoughts were correct. It's just that this person is normally correct about a lot of things...

Comment: @IskyMathews There is a typo - I presume you mean $f(a)$ in your definition for continuity, not $a$...

Comment: @IskyMathews BTW, you should know that often in analysis you make the assumption that all removable singularities have been redefined, e.g. when discussing meromorphic functions we assume the only singularities are poles. In that sense, we would say your function is continuous at 0. (In some sense, we are discussing a quotient space where we view functions the same everywhere but as removable singularities as equal)

Comment: There is no such thing as $(\sin 0)/0.$ The statement that  $F(x)$ tends to a limit $L$ as $x\to 0$  means only what is says.  The definition of  $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x)=L $implicitly or explicitly requires that $x$ is restricted to members of the domain of $F.$  And $0$ is not in the domain of $(\sin x)/x.$

Comment: @IskyMathews if ur gna edit ur post like that, write edit so its clear ur heading our advice - otherwise makes our comments look nonsensical!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I presume there is a typo in line 3 which should read "$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ equal to $f(a)$", not "$a$." Quite simply, $f(0)$ is undefined, and so this is what we call a removable discontinuity. Indeed, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(sinx)/x$ does exist and, by L'Hopitals Rule is equal to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}cosx=1$. However, as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ exists but has a value different from $f(0)$ (in this case undefined), we have a removable discontinuity.

If you want a very interesting problem: Let $f$ be an arbitrary function from the $R$ to $R$ (reals). Consider $D_f$, the set of points of points at which f is discontinuous. Show that $D_f$ is a F-sigma set - that is, $D_f$ can be written as the countable union of closed sets (hint: first consider monotone functions, then generalise from there).

Speak spoon g

NOTE: functional limits require $a$ to be a limit point of the domain (as 0 is in this case), however, v. important subtle difference is that continuity requires that $a$ actually be contained in the domain, and of course in this case, 0 is not as $sin0/0$ is undefined.

Comment: @IskyMathews what u think?

Answer (score 7):

It only makes sense to talk about continuity for points $x$ in the domain of  the function, so asking if $\sin x/x$ is continuous at $0$ is not well-posed.  However, we can define a function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sin x/x&x \neq  0\\
1&x=0
\end{cases}
$$
which is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, this someone was right (though I bet many people here will disagree).

Because writing $\dfrac{\sin 0}0$ can be taken informally for an indeterminate expression where the limit of $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ is implied (otherwise one would have written $\dfrac{\sin 0}{0^2}$ or $\dfrac{\log(\sin0+1)}0$ or...), and because the natural choice for the value of the function when it is indeterminate is the limit.

So even if the statement lacks rigor, it can be understood as "the value of $\dfrac{\sin(0)}0$ should be $1$", and that makes the function continuous.

By the way the "official" cardinal sine function is so defined.

Comment: In fact that $\sin\alpha \approx \alpha \approx \tan\alpha$ as $\alpha \to 0$, is known since *millennia* (and later refined with the Taylor series).

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is undefined at 0, it is not continuous at 0.